# Get header:row_data from CSV file python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, dictionary, pandas

I have a csv file like below

```
h1,h2,h3,h4
a,b,,d
1,2,3,4
a1,,h5,jj
```

I'd like to get a list like this:
For example, for 'a', I need `h1:a,h2:b,h4:d`. I could get headers and row data separately, however, I'm unable to concatenate them in the desired way. Also, I don't want blanks to be printed as 'nan'

Comment: You mean a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @reptilicus Yes. But it should print for only one element of h1, i.e., a or 1 or a1. I tried `{rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}` for the complete dictionary but the output looked horrible.

Comment: df.to_dict('records') might work?

Comment: It gives 'nan' for blank cells. I'd like them to be ignored completely. @reptilicus

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv('some_file')
for row in df.to_dict('records'):
   print {k:v for k,v in row.iteritems() if v is not np.nan}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with the csv module and dict comprehensions:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as f:                                                                                                                                  
        reader = csv.reader(f)                                                                                                                                        
        result = []                                                                                                                                                   
        header = reader.next()                                                                                                                                        
        for row in reader:                                                                                                                                            
            result.append({k: v for k, v in zip(header, row) if v != ''})
```

Answer (score 1):

You also can use my wrapper library over csv module to do it:

```
>>> import pyexcel as pe
>>> s=pe.load("example.csv", name_columns_by_row=0)
>>> records = s.to_records()
>>> records
[{'h2': u'b', 'h3': u'', 'h1': u'a', 'h4': u'd'}, {'h2': u'2', 'h3': u'3', 'h1': u'1', 'h4': u'4'}, {'h2': u'', 'h3': u'h5', 'h1': u'a1', 'h4': u'jj'}]
>>> s.column['h1']
[u'a', u'1', u'a1']
>>> zip(s.column['h1'], records)
[(u'a', {'h2': u'b', 'h3': u'', 'h1': u'a', 'h4': u'd'}), (u'1', {'h2': u'2', 'h3': u'3', 'h1': u'1', 'h4': u'4'}), (u'a1', {'h2': u'', 'h3': u'h5', 'h1': u'a1', 'h4': u'jj'})]
```

More documentation can be found [here](https://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)